# Sending SMS via Android Application without moving to Message Box Default Application

Tags: java, android

I want to ask you: 
1-How can I send  SMS via my applicatin without moving the user to the Messages box 
i just want to allow user to insert the text then he/she clicks on the send button
after that directly the text message should be sent to specific number that i write in the code?

I used this Code as shown below, it works well, but it moved me to the message box :(
any Suggestions ?

```
MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String str= MyEditText.getText().toString();
                // For SMS
                Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("I wrote my number here");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Besm Allah");
                intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

====================== After Updating ================================

[image: Why (SmsManger) word appears like this (with lines)]

Comment: use `sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI)` method of `SMSManager`

Comment: @imrankhan thanks alot, do you mean this is a built-in function? if yes what's the mean of sendPI and deliverdPI?
and do you mean the receiver number by phoneNumber ???
thanks so much ...

Comment: yes this is built-in function in SMSmanager : sentPI an PendingIntent for receiving sent delivery report , deliverdPI an PendingIntent for receiving delivery report , phoneNumber to which we want to send sms and null is service center number .for more help see [send Sms](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

Comment: @imrankhan do you know what's the problem with this code ?

Comment: you are using `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager`, which is deprecated. see `android.telephony.SmsManager` instead. Check you imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an Intent object (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ... ) which invokes the built-in SMS application to help you send an SMS message. Therefore you are redirected to the message box.

For sending message process to be completed without being directed to the message box you need to use `PendingIntent`. Take a look at this great SMS tutorial which would quite possibly solve your problem.  http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the provided intent. That allows the user to choose which app to use to send SMS. This is the way Android is designed. It gives the user choice about how apps can send SMS.

If you want to send SMS without the user using their chosen app, then you will need to use an SMS API from a commercial provider (e.g. esendex), and pay them to send SMS for you.

Comment: thanks, but can you explain more your 2nd sentence, if you mean we have to pay to network provider, we did talk with them about that, and we'll use unique number as A Receiver number (our server), because of that we should hide the steps of sending SMS from user and show it as chatting as in Whatsapp ? hope my problem being more clear now ...

Answer (score 0):

```
//---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
}
```

Take a [close look at SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) to learn what all of the parameters will do for you.

Also here is the tutorial that this code snippet came from: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Answer (score 0):

I found the Perfect Sol. :

```
// Inside OnCreate()
Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HelperWordStr= HelperWords.getText().toString();
                // For SMS
                if (!b) {
                    try {
                                                    sendSMS("Receiver Number", HelperWordStr);
                        Toast.makeText(ChattingPage.this, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(ChattingPage.this, e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

// Outside 

    public void sendSMS(String number, String msg) throws Exception {
        if (!b) {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, null, null);
        }
        b = true;
    }
```